# Spring boot - Token online verification

Tags: spring-boot

I'm developing an app.
Front/bff/api.
I'm using an open id provider that allows to check token remotely.
The bff intercepts the front requests and sends them to the API with the jwt token in the header.
The api should ask the open ip provider if the token is correct (but remotely, not using the offline mode with the public key ).
The api is a spring boot 3.0.1 project.
How to configure security in spring boot 3.0.1 to do that check?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You do that with access-token introspection. In spring-security conf, that means using `opaqueToken()` instead of `jwt()` (the first configures a resource-server with introspection and the second with a JWT decoder).

Be aware that token introspection is far less efficient than using a JWT decoder as a request is sent to the authorization-server for each and every request to a resource-server. [Tutorial there](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/tree/master/samples/tutorials/resource-server_with_introspection).